# Referencing c# assembuly due to vb.net conversion problems

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

After converting code from c# to vb.net, pointers and unsafe code there's a problem, and due to the application i need to use them, so i've read about creating an assembuly and referencing it in a vb.net application. i've got so far but im not sure how to go about it now. Pointer (Of Byte) Problem

```
Public Function Recognize(image As UnmanagedImage, rect As Rectangle, ByRef confidence As Single) As Byte(,)
        Dim glyphStartX As Integer = rect.Left
        Dim glyphStartY As Integer = rect.Top
        Dim glyphWidth As Integer = rect.Width
        Dim glyphHeight As Integer = rect.Height
        Dim cellWidth As Integer = glyphWidth \ glyphSize
        Dim cellHeight As Integer = glyphHeight \ glyphSize
        Dim cellOffsetX As Integer = CInt(cellWidth * 0.2)
        Dim cellOffsetY As Integer = CInt(cellHeight * 0.2)
        Dim cellScanX As Integer = CInt(cellWidth * 0.6)
        Dim cellScanY As Integer = CInt(cellHeight * 0.6)
        Dim cellScanArea As Integer = cellScanX * cellScanY
        Dim cellIntensity As Integer(,) = New Integer(glyphSize - 1, glyphSize - 1) {}
        Dim stride As Integer = image.Stride
        Dim srcBase As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(image.ImageData.ToPointer(), Pointer(Of Byte)) + (glyphStartY + cellOffsetY) * stride + glyphStartX + cellOffsetX
        Dim srcLine As Pointer(Of Byte)
        Dim src As Pointer(Of Byte)
        For gi As Integer = 0 To glyphSize - 1
            srcLine = srcBase + cellHeight * gi * stride
            For y As Integer = 0 To cellScanY - 1
                For gj As Integer = 0 To glyphSize - 1
                    src = srcLine + cellWidth * gj
                    Dim x As Integer = 0
                    While x < cellScanX
                        cellIntensity(gi, gj) += src.Target
                        x += 1
                        src += 1
                    End While
                Next
                srcLine += stride
            Next
        Next

        ' calculate value of each glyph's cell and set
        ' glyphs' confidence to minim value of cell's confidence
        Dim glyphValues As Byte(,) = New Byte(glyphSize - 1, glyphSize - 1) {}
        confidence = 1.0F
        For gi As Integer = 0 To glyphSize - 1
            For gj As Integer = 0 To glyphSize - 1
                Dim fullness As Single = CSng(cellIntensity(gi, gj) / 255) / cellScanArea
                Dim conf As Single = CSng(System.Math.Abs(fullness - 0.5)) + 0.5F
                glyphValues(gi, gj) = CByte(If((fullness > 0.5F), 1, 0))
                If conf < confidence Then
                    confidence = conf
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return glyphValues
    End Function
```

So i created a c# project and placed the code original c# part of the code within it namespace CTCAM:

```
public interface interfaceCTCAM
{
int Recognize(UnmanagedImage image, Rectangle rect, out float confidence);

}
public class Class1
{

public byte[,] Recognize(UnmanagedImage image, Rectangle rect, out float confidence)
{

int glyphSize = 5;
int glyphStartX = rect.Left;
int glyphStartY = rect.Top;
int glyphWidth = rect.Width;
int glyphHeight = rect.Height;
int cellWidth = glyphWidth / glyphSize;
int cellHeight = glyphHeight / glyphSize;
int cellOffsetX = (int)(cellWidth * 0.2);
int cellOffsetY = (int)(cellHeight * 0.2);
int cellScanX = (int)(cellWidth * 0.6);
int cellScanY = (int)(cellHeight * 0.6);
int cellScanArea = cellScanX * cellScanY;
int[,] cellIntensity = new int[glyphSize, glyphSize];
unsafe
{
int stride = image.Stride;
byte* srcBase = (byte*)image.ImageData.ToPointer() +
(glyphStartY + cellOffsetY) * stride +
glyphStartX + cellOffsetX;
byte* srcLine;
byte* src;
for (int gi = 0; gi < glyphSize; gi++)
{
srcLine = srcBase + cellHeight * gi * stride;
for (int y = 0; y < cellScanY; y++)
{
for (int gj = 0; gj < glyphSize; gj++)
{
src = srcLine + cellWidth * gj;
for (int x = 0; x < cellScanX; x++, src++)
{
cellIntensity[gi, gj] += *src;
}
}
srcLine += stride;
}
}
}

// calculate value of each glyph's cell and set
// glyphs' confidence to minim value of cell's confidence
byte[,] glyphValues = new byte[glyphSize, glyphSize];
confidence = 1f;
for (int gi = 0; gi < glyphSize; gi++)
{
for (int gj = 0; gj < glyphSize; gj++)
{
float fullness = (float)
(cellIntensity[gi, gj] / 255) / cellScanArea;
float conf = (float)System.Math.Abs(fullness - 0.5) + 0.5f;
glyphValues[gi, gj] = (byte)((fullness > 0.5f) ? 1 : 0);
if (conf < confidence)
confidence = conf;
}
}
return glyphValues;
}

}
```

Once i done that i deleted the "recognized" function from the vb code and imported the libary created "Imports CTCAM.Class1".

So in the VB application, Later in my code and error is showing, and this is where im not sure where to go now.

```
Dim glyphValues As Byte(,) = Recognize(glyphImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, glyphImage.Width, glyphImage.Height), confidence)
```

The word "Recognize" is highlighted with the following error information: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Any help would be great.

Many Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an instance of 'Class1'

```
Dim class1instance As New Class1()
Dim glyphValues As Byte(,) = class1instance.Recognize(glyphImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, glyphImage.Width, glyphImage.Height), confidence)
```

Another option would be to make the function Shared.